# How do I get a website's IP address using Python 3.x?

Tags: python, dns, ip

I have a string representing a domain name. How can I get the corresponding IP address using Python 3.x? Something like this:

```
>>> get_ip('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
'64.34.119.12'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve DNS in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837744/how-to-resolve-dns-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> import socket

>>> def get_ips_for_host(host):
        try:
            ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(host)
        except socket.gaierror:
            ips=[]
        return ips

>>> ips = get_ips_for_host('www.google.com')
>>> print(repr(ips))
('www.l.google.com', [], ['74.125.77.104', '74.125.77.147', '74.125.77.99'])
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('cool-rr.com')
'174.120.139.162'
```

Note that:

- gethostbyname() doesn't work with [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).
- gethostbyname() uses the C call gethostbanme(), which is deprecated.

If these are problematic, use socket.getaddrinfo() instead.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use [`socket.gethostbyname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).  This does not support IPv6, though, and is based on the deprecated C call `gethostbanme()`.  If you care about these problems, you can use the more versatile [`socket.getaddrinfo()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example, how you can get  a website's IP address using Python

```py
import urllib.parse
import socket
import dns.resolver

def get_ip(target):
    try:
        print(socket.gethostbyname(target))
    except socket.gaierror:
        res = head(target, allow_redirects=True)
        try:
            print(r.headers['Host'])
        except KeyError:
            parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(target)
            hostname = parsed_url.hostname
            try:
                answers = dns.resolver.query(hostname, 'A')
                for rdata in answers:
                    print(rdata.address)
            except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
                print('ip not found')

get_ip('example.com')
```