# Efficiently retrieve IP address and status code

Tags: sockets, python-2.7

Just a practical question. I do need to retrieve the HTTP status code of a site as well as the IP address.

Given the fact I normally need to parse between 10k and 150k domains, I was wondering which is the most efficient method.

I've seen that using the urllib2.urlopen(site) attempts to download the entire file stream connected to the file. At the same time the urllibs2 doesn't offer a method to convert an hostname into an IP.

Given I'm interested only in the HEAD bit to collect information like the HTTP status code and the IP address of that specific server, what is the best way to operate?

SHould I try to use only the socket? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no one particular magic tool that will retrieve the HTTP status code of a site and the IP address.

For getting HTTP status code you should make a `HEAD` request using `urllib2` or `httplib` or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Here's an example, taken from [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
...     def get_method(self):
...         return "HEAD"
... 
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest("http://google.com/index.html"))
```

An example, using `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.head('http://google.com').status_code
301
```

Also, you might want to take a look at [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) in order to speed things up with getting status codes from multiple pages.

> GRequests allows you to use Requests with Gevent to make asyncronous
>   HTTP Requests easily.

For getting an IP address, you should use `socket`:

```
 socket.gethostbyname_ex('google.com')
```

Also see these threads:

- [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)
- [How to resolve DNS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837744/how-to-resolve-dns-in-python)
- [How do I get a website's IP address using Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815065/how-do-i-get-a-websites-ip-address-using-python-3-x)

Hope that helps.

Comment: So there is not any chance to do this without making two calls?